# How to Edit and Run Local PHP File in Objective-C and Swift

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, swift

I have a set of locally stored PHP files that I need to edit and run inside my iOS app. How can I do that in Objective-C and Swift? I tried to search for answers on the web but I can't get the exact answer that I need. I can access the php files using this code:

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *phpFile = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"getinfo" ofType:@"php"];

NSLog(@"Main bundle path: %@", mainBundle);
NSLog(@"phpFile path: %@", phpFile);
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't, at least not without writing your own parser and interpreter (which seems possible, as demonstrated by [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/kodiak-php/id542685332?mt=8)).

Your options are to replicate the functionality of the php files in Objective-C or Swift, or to have them execute on a server.

Comment: Thanks Mundi. Just what I thought. Just needed confirmation that it isn't possible.